# On using Radial Basis Functions to approximate nonlinear data set

Tags: optimization, approximation, interpolation

I have a two dimensional function represented by 3 data set

$f_i(\omega_i,\beta_i)=\psi_i$  such that $i \in [1,N]$

How can I do the following:

- First interpolate to larger data points using Radial Basis Function but want to increase the interpolating points such 
  $ g_k \equiv f_i $ with $ k \in [1,M] ; M > N $
- Approximate $g$ using Radial Basis Functions or Similar algorithm for reconstructing the function.

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @fang Read the question